# I'm trying to skip over errors and warnings in this for loop in r but its not working?

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling

I am trying to read csv files with their names as dates into a for loop and then print out a few columns of data from that file when it is actually there. I need to skip over the dates that I don't have any data for and the dates that don't actually exist. When I put in my code there is no output, it is just blank. Why doesn't my code work?

```
options(width=10000)

options(warn=2)

for(a in 3:5){
for(b in 0:1){
for(c in 0:9){
for(d in 0:3){
for(e in 0:9){

mydata=try(read.csv(paste("201",a,b,c,d,e,".csv",sep="")), silent=TRUE)

if(class(mydata)=="try-error"){next}

else{

    mydata$Data <- do.call(paste, c(mydata[c("LAST_UPDATE_DT","px_last")], sep=""))
    print(t(mydata[,c('X','Data')]))
}

}}}}}
```

Comment: if you're interested in using `data.table` (make sure to use 1.8.9), then: `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))` should do it. And it's extremely fast.

Comment: do this to install the package: `install.packages("data.table",
repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really terrible way to read in all your files. Try this:

```
f <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
mydata <- sapply(f, read.csv, simplify=FALSE)
```

This will return a list `mydata` of data frames, each of which is the contents of the corresponding file.

Or, if there are other csv files that you *don't* want to read in, you can restrict the specification:

```
f <- list.files(pattern="201\\d{5}\\.csv")
```

---

And to combine everything into one big data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, mydata)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to combine the data frames into one?

Comment: How would you pick specific columns to combine?